# Google map pin title from json array

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have a map which i am populating from a json array.

I pass a multidimensional array and convert to json:

```
public List<string[]> locationList { get; set; }

var locs = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.locationList));
```

Map code using postcode:

```
var map;
var elevator;
var myOptions = {
    zoom: 5,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(53.90, -3.00),
    mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
};

map = new google.maps.Map($('#map_canvas_locations')[0], myOptions);

var latlng;   

for (var i = 0; i < locs.length; i++) {
    var name = locs[i][1];
    var markerdata = $.getJSON('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=' + locs[i][0] + '&sensor=false', null, function (data) {
        var p = data.results[0].geometry.location
        latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(p.lat, p.lng);

        new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latlng,
            map: map,
            title: name,
        });           
    });
};
```

The problem seems to be with title. If I try using json value directly no pins show:

```
new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latlng,
            map: map,
            title: locs[i][1],
        });
```

If I try assigning the value to a var I get all the map pins but they all have what seems to be the last entry's title:

```
var name = locs[i][1];    

new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latlng,
            map: map,
            title: name,
        });
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Any errors in the console?  Is the value of `locs[i][1]` a number?  Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is the options for `google.maps.Marker` are wrapped in a closure `{}`

so you end up passing a reference to `i` which ends up as the last value

use `forEach` instead of traditional `for` loop

the presence of the `function` should allow `name` to keep it's value

```
locs.forEach(function (name) {
    var markerdata = $.getJSON('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=' + locs[i][0] + '&sensor=false', null, function (data) {
        var p = data.results[0].geometry.location
        latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(p.lat, p.lng);

        new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latlng,
            map: map,
            title: name
        });
    });
});
```

for more, here's the real answer...
[JavaScript closure inside loops](https://stackoverflow.com/a/750506/5090771)